# Select Editor in Extended WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, toolkit, xceed

Using PropertyGrid from Extended WPF Toolkit. I would like to select a built-in editor for a field.

I know I can get it from the model, this way:

```
[Editor(typeof(TextBoxEditor), typeof(TextBoxEditor))]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

But I would like to get it from XAML, something like this (of course it is NOT valid):

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
    <xctk:PropertyDefinition TargetProperties="PetNames" Editor="TextBoxEditor" />
</xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
```

Is there a way to show a property in a not-default editor, without changing my model?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your question but I think that setting the model of the control specifically could solve your problem (you keep the model of the entire view and just change the one from the affected control).

Comment: I mean a way to specify an editor from XAML, so I do not have to specify it in C# with an attribute. Thank  you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, in the [documentation](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid#custom-editors-with-datatemplates), you may create a custom editor using DataTemplates by setting the `EditingTemplate` like so:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
    <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition TargetProperties="PetNames">
        <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- put whatever control you would like here (including your own custom one) -->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
    </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition>
</xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach, although your code is wrong. You cannot put a EditorTemplateDefinition inside a PropertyDefinition (it must be outside, in a EditorDefinitions label). There must be two different blocks in PropertyGrid: EditorDefinitions and PropertyDefinitions. If you fix it, I will mark your answer as the accepted one. Thank you

Comment: Good catch. I'm not sure why I had the other code there. In any case, I have updated it.